# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) in AOSP middleware

Tags: c, android-source

I am trying to concatenate the string like below

```
typedef struct IInfo
  {
    char cmAddress[6];                      
    UINT8 IpAddress[4];                     
    UINT8 hIpAddress[4];                    
  } IInfo;
```

In my file:

```
     IInfo Info;
    char CableIP[50];

   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"test","test--> %s:%d IpAddress[0] : %d,IpAddress[1] : %d,IpAddress[2] : %d,IpAddress[3] : %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, Info.IpAddress[0], Info.IpAddress[1],Info.IpAddress[2], Info.IpAddress[3]);


    strcpy(CableIP,Info.IpAddress[0]);//10
    strcat(CableIP,"." );
    strcat(CableIP,Info.IpAddress[1] );//1
    strcat(CableIP,"." );
    strcat(CableIP,Info.IpAddress[2] );//120
    strcat(CableIP,"." );
    strcat(CableIP,Info.IpAddress[3] );//36
    printf("CableIP %s",CableIP);
```

getting print like below:
test: test--> _ExecuteFUN:298 IpAddress[0] : 10,IpAddress[1] : 1,IpAddress[2] : 120,IpAddress[3] : 36

Expecting output is   10.1.120.36

but getting below error
F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xa in tid 2888 (n0000001)

An individual array element print getting proper data, but if I do concatenation getting an error.

can you please suggest to me, where I have done wrong?

Comment: Are all the elements of `IpAddress` strings as well? By the way you could probably reduce this all to 1 line with `snprintf`.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Info`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have updated the question , could you please check

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 IpAddress is a structure element.

Comment: You might want to read the compiler warnings. You're missing the `&` operator in a bunch of places. It ought to be `strcpy(CableIP, &Info.IpAddress[0]);` etc.

Comment: Although even then this would not work, because `strcpy` and `strcat` expects pointers to NUL-terminated strings, and that's not what you've got in your array. Just use some variant of `sprintf` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   char *strcpy(char *restrict dest, const char *src);
```

> The `strcpy()` function copies the string pointed to by `src`,
> including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`), to the buffer pointed
> to by `dest`. - [For more](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html)

`Info.IpAddress` is of type array of `UINT8` rather than `char*`.

I would prefer as following

```
sprintf(CableIP, "%u.%u.%u.%u%c", Info.IpAddress[0], Info.IpAddress[1], Info.IpAddress[2], Info.IpAddress[3], '\0');
```